# Planning to use sdn4 , i dont see travesal api support in sdn4 ..so what are my options

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Planning to use sdn4 , i dont see travesal api support in sdn4 ..so what are my options. Shall I develop unmanaged extension with sdn3 perhaps..?

Answer (score 1):

SDN 4.0 supports only HTTP interaction with a remote neo4j server, and the traversal API is unavailable for use. In this case, you can use unmanaged extensions.

SDN 4.1 (currently in version RC1) supports both remote Neo4j as well as embedded, so if you are using the embedded graph database, then you can get a handle to it like this and use the Neo4j Java API as usual:

```
EmbeddedDriver embeddedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) Components.driver();
GraphDatabaseService databaseService = embeddedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService();
```

Unmanaged extensions will be required if you use the remote Neo4j server.

Comment: I want to write unmanaged extension with traversal apis which one would be better neo4j-jdbc or sdn (if so which version) or others